# cocos2d sprite collision detection, one sprite sometimes has a contentSize.width of 0.000000

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hello I am having some trouble with collision detection in a cocos2d game. I am working on a game where I need to test if a bullet hits the character. I am using the CGRectIntersectsRect method to see if the collision happens. In the simulator you can see the bullet pass over the character but nothing happens. I want the character to disappear if a bullet hits it. In my code I have a CCLOG statement that outputs "COLLISION" if a bullet hits the character. Also I have two other CCLOG statements that output the contentSize.width of the bullet and the character. The bullet's contentSize.width should be 20.0 but sometimes it outputs the width as 0. Here is the code for the collision detection.

```
-(void)testForBulletCollision:(ccTime)delta{
CCLOG(@"bullet.contentsize.width = %f",bullet.contentSize.width);
CCLOG(@"character.contentsize.width = %f",character.contentSize.width);
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([bullet boundingBox], [character boundingBox]))
{
    CCLOG(@"BULLET COLLISION");
    character.visible = NO;
    bullet.visible = NO;
}
}
```

Here is the code for creating the character.

```
character = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mcharacter.png"];
    character.position = ccp(screenWidth/3.4, screenHeight/2 - 100);
    [self addChild:character z:-3];
```

Here is the code for creating the bullet and the bullet animation.

```
-(void)shootTheBullets:(ccTime)delta{
bullet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"thebullet.png"];
bullet.color = ccRED;
bullet.position = redEnemy.position;
[self addChild:bullet z:-1];
bulletRect = CGRectMake(bullet.position.x - (bullet.contentSize.width/2),
                        bullet.position.y - (bullet.contentSize.height/2),
                        bullet.contentSize.width,
                        bullet.contentSize.height);


CCLOG(@"bullet.contentSize.width = %f", bullet.contentSize.width);
bulletMoveLeft = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:4.0 position:ccp(-screenWidth,       screenHeight/2)];
[bullet runAction:bulletMoveLeft];

[self schedule: @selector(stopBullets:)interval:18.0f/1.0f];
}

-(void)stopBullets:(ccTime)delta{
[self unschedule:@selector(shootTheBullets:)];
}
```

Here is the output.

2013-08-07 16:31:43.637 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.638 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.638 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.638 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.639 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.639 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.685 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.686 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.686 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.687 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.687 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.688 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.688 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.689 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.689 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.690 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.691 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentSize.width = 20.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.836 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.837 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.838 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.838 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.839 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.840 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.841 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 0.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.842 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.843 Zach App[1320:a0b] bullet.contentsize.width = 20.000000
2013-08-07 16:31:43.843 Zach App[1320:a0b] character.contentsize.width = 64.000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every time you call 'shootTheBullets', you are replacing the pointer that 'bullet' points to, which I would guess is why your content size reports 0, as the pointer is no longer pointing to the original object. You should be collecting your bullets in an array or similar and iterating through those to see if the bounding boxes intersect with your character.

edit:

I'm not sure why you'd be given a CCNode back when you put in a CCSprite, but in any case, here's a simple snippet of your basic requirement --  bullets, a character, bullet damage, character damage.

Disclaimer: It's for cc2d 1.1, non-ARC . It's what I have handy right now.

**Bullet.h**

```
#import "CCSprite.h"

@interface Bullet : CCSprite
{
    float damage;
    CGPoint velocity;
}

@property float damage;
@property CGPoint velocity;

+(Bullet *) bulletWithDamage:(float) damage andVelocity:(CGPoint) velocity;

@end
```

**Bullet.m**

```
#import "Bullet.h"
@implementation Bullet
@synthesize damage, velocity;
+(Bullet *) bulletWithDamage:(float) damage andVelocity:(CGPoint) velocity
{
    Bullet *bullet = [[[self alloc] initWithFile:@"Icon.png"] autorelease];
    bullet.damage = damage;
    bullet.velocity = velocity;
    bullet.scale = 0.2f;
    return bullet;
}

-(id) init
{
    if( (self = [super init]) )
    {}
    return self;
}
@end
```

**PlayTest.h**

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface PlayTest : CCLayer
{
    NSMutableArray *bullets;
    CCSprite *character;
    CGSize winSize;
}

@end
```

**PlayTest.m**

```
#import "PlayTest.h"
#import "Bullet.h"

@implementation PlayTest

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        bullets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 10];

        character = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
        character.position = ccp(winSize.width/3.4f, winSize.height/2.0f - 100.0f);
        [self addChild:character z:-3];

        [self schedule:@selector(shootTheBullets:) interval:1.0f repeat: 10 delay: 3.0f];
        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)shootTheBullets:(ccTime)delta{

    float randX = CCRANDOM_0_1() * 0.5f;
    Bullet *b = [Bullet bulletWithDamage:5.0f andVelocity:ccp( randX, -1.0f)];
    b.position = ccp(40.0f, winSize.height);
    [bullets addObject:b];

    [self addChild: b];

}

-(void) update:(ccTime)dt
{
    [self moveTheBullets];
    [self checkCollisions];
}

-(void) moveTheBullets
{
    for (int i=0; i< bullets.count; i++)
    {
        Bullet *b = (Bullet *)[bullets objectAtIndex:i];
        b.position = ccpAdd(b.position, b.velocity);
    }
}

-(void) checkCollisions
{
    NSMutableArray *collisions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    BOOL characterHit = NO;
    for (int i=0; i< bullets.count; i++)
    {
        Bullet *b = (Bullet *)[bullets objectAtIndex:i];
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(character.boundingBox, b.boundingBox) )
        {
            NSLog(@"bullet collision with character");
            [collisions addObject: b];
            characterHit = YES;
        }
        else if (b.position.y < 0.0f)
        {
            NSLog(@"bullet went off screen without hitting anything");
            [collisions addObject: b];
            b.damage = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i< collisions.count; i++)
    {
        Bullet *b = (Bullet *)[collisions objectAtIndex:i];

        // you could damage the character here, something like:
        // characterDamage -= b.damage


        [self removeChild:b cleanup:YES];
        [bullets removeObject: b];
        NSLog(@"bullets count is %d", bullets.count);
    }

    if(characterHit) // show character got damaged
    {
        if( ![character numberOfRunningActions])
        {
            id one = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:0.1f key:@"opacity" from:255 to:128];
            id two = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:0.1f key:@"opacity" from:128 to:255];
            id onetwo = [CCSequence actions: one, two, nil];
            [character runAction: onetwo];
        }
    }
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [bullets release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hello, I added an array called arrayOfBullets and wrote [arrayOfBullets addObject:bullet]; after [bullet runAction: bulletMoveLeft]; in the shootTheBullets method. Then i added for (bullet in arrayOfBullets){  before the if statement in the testForBulletCollision method, but I am still getting the same results. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: hard to tell without seeing more code.. are you removing bullets somewhere else, not just setting them to 'visible=NO'? and did you get rid of the ivar 'bullet' ?

Comment: I am not removing any bullets, just creating them, doing the CCAction to them, adding them to the array, and then iterating through the array to find if any bullets collide. My output is the same. Is all the code I have ok??

Comment: As I said to LearnCocos2D the bullet CCSprite is of CCNode and he said that that might be why bullet has a contentSize.width of 0. Do You think that is why the array is not working??

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses and answer! The code you gave me worked!

Answer (score 0):

There are theoretically three reasons:

- `bullet` is nil when you log its contentSize
- bullet's contentSize is nil because it is either a CCNode or a "visual" node without a texture
- bullet's contentSize has been modified

The first is easy to test (assert for non-nil). The second is to verify that bullet actually is of the right class (for example using isKindOfClass:). The last you can test by adding a breakpoint or logging inside CCNode's setContentSize: method.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I found out that the bullet is a CCNode. How do I fix this??